# How to provide temporary download url in Flask?

Tags: python, authentication, download, flask, session-timeout

Currently, my `index.html` file contains

```
<a href="static/file.ext">Download</a>
```

I want to change this so that the download url is only valid for a certain time. For example, how would I change it to

```
<a href="get_file?file=file.ext&token=TEMPORARYTOKEN">Download</a>
```

In my Flask file, I could then have

```
@app.route('/get_file')
def get_file():
    filename = request.args.get('file')
    token = request.args.get('token')
    if token is valid: # what can be done here
        return send_from_directory('static', filename)
```

How can I generate and handle the token? Or am I approaching this completely wrong?

Comment: While I think your question is correct, I wanted to discuss one thing related to this. Just because of this constraint, we'll be forcing the framework(django/flask/RoR) to stream the file back, whereas I would have loved it if there was a solution in which we could get nginx/apache to serve it.

Comment: Is there a better way to provide temporary authentication for downloads using nginx or apache? How would it communicate with the rest of the program?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: By framework do you mean something like `Flask`, or do you mean something else? As of now, I am just using `Flask`'s built-in `run()` method to run the server locally, but for production I will probably deploy to a third-party server such as Heroku.

Comment: @darkryder `send_from_directory` and `send_file` from flask support `X-Sendfile` header, which delegates the actual sending of the file to the web server (usually nginx with flask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

1. Generate a UUID for your token and store it in a db table along with the desired expiration datetime. Then when someone calls the URL with the token, you can just check it against the db for validity and expiration.
2. If you don't want to use a db to store the tokens, you can use GPG to encrypt a string that contains the expiration datetime and use the resulting encrypted string as your token. This means your token will be a lot longer than a UUID, but you'd avoid having to use a db.

I recommend using UUID and a db table.

Comment: instead of reinventing the wheel with GPG, for option 2 one should use `itsdangerous` package, which is already a flask dependency and has methods for this purpose specifically (URL signing). Security is hard to get right, one should always prefer to use a proven and audited lib that stood the test of time instead of coming up with your own encrypting/signing mechanisms.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to do that is to use `itsdangerous` package. You can generate a URL that last whatever time you want. Furthermore you could encode secretly any information within the URL. The good thing about that is that NO need to deal or store timestamps into the database

To generate a URL that last for 30 mins and encode user id within the token

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer

s = Serializer('WEBSITE_SECRET_KEY', 60*30) # 60 secs by 30 mins
token = s.dumps({'user_id': currentuser.id}).decode('utf-8') # encode user id
```

Use the following to generate the URL you want

```
url_for('get_file', token=token)
```

To validate a URL

```
@app.route('/get_file/<token>')
def get_file(token):
    s = Serializer('WEBSITE_SECRET_KEY')
    try:
        user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
    except:
        return None
    user = User.query.get(user_id)

    if not user:
        flash('This is an invalid or expired URL, please generate a new one!', 'warning')
        return redirect(url_for('another_route'))

    return send_from_directory('static', filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should use hmac.

Generate link

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
secret = "anything you like"  # such as generate from os.urandom(length)
def generate(filename):
    current_time = str(int(time.time()))
    token = hmac.new(secret, current_time, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return "get_file?file=%(filename)s&time=%(current_time)s&token=%(token)s" % {
        "filename": filename,
        "current_time": current_time,
        "token": token
    }
```

Verify link

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
secret = "anything you like"  # same as in generate function
def verify(time_in_link, token_in_link):
    time_limit = 15 * 60  # maximum time in sec(such as: 15(mins) * 60 (convert them to sec)`enter code here`) that you want them to start download after the link has been generated.
    if (time.time() - int(time_in_link)) > time_limit:  #timeout, return False
        return False
    if hmac.new(secret, str(time_in_link), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest() == token_in_link:  # Check the token is available or not
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `itsdangerous` package already does that, handling all HMAC and time calculation for you automatically and is already a flask dependency. Security is hard to get right, one should always prefer to use a proven and audited lib that stood the test of time instead of coming up with your own encrypting/signing mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Something I came up with in the shower:

```
from flask import Flask
import datetime as dt
import hashlib

app = Flask(__name__)

time_lock = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

@app.route('/')
def home():
    security_code = hashlib.sha256(time_lock.encode())
    return f"<a href='/test/{security_code.hexdigest()}'>Click Here</a>"


@app.route('/test/<security_code>')
def test(security_code):
    master_code = hashlib.sha256(time_lock.encode())
    if security_code == master_code.digest():
        return "Access granted!"
```

What this is doing is using a hash of the current date as a temporary URL. Obviously has security flaws but it's a crazy idea that does work and could be built upon to be more secure. Its very similar to the chosen answer but doesn't use persistent storage. This would be suited for securing links from being bookmarked possibly?

Answer (score -2):

Another way would be to encode the primary key from the db in base64. That's usually how the short url-services all over the net get the short urls. The db ensures uniqueness and since it's base64 it'll take quite a few files before the urls grow long.

On every request you then check your db to see if the link is still valid. If it isn't you do something meaningful with the request.